# Clip using not existing node

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm looking for a proper way to clip "afterwards". Indeed, I want to clip to a coordinate of a node I don't know yet. So I need to draw it first and then I can clip. But the clipping applies only on the commands after... so it's too late.

For the moment I draw the plot in a phantom like node (no style at all), and then I plot it another time, but I think it's very dirty, if the picture is big I do not want to plot twice my picture.

Here is the (good) result I want (note the nice cut at the middle):

[image: good result]

and the bad code I'm using (by the way do not hesitate to tell me any better way to code in tikz when I do not use the good tool) :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,matrix,chains,positioning,decorations.pathreplacing,arrows,fit,patterns,calc,decorations.markings,decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds}

\begin{document} 

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  a/.style = {draw},
  box/.style = {draw,opacity=0.7,inner sep=0.2em,rounded rectangle}
  ]
  \matrix[matrix of nodes,text depth=0.3em,text height=1em,column sep=-\pgflinewidth](ma){
    |[a]| $a_1$ & |[a]| $a_2$ & |[a]| $\dots$ & |[a]| $a_{m-2}$ & |[a]| $a_{m-1}$ & |[a]| $a_{m}$&
    |[a]| $a_1$ & |[a]| $a_2$ & |[a]| $\dots$ & |[a]| $a_{m-2}$ & |[a]| $a_{m-1}$ & |[a]| $a_{m}$& |[a]| $\dots$&
    |[a]| $a_1$ & |[a]| $a_2$ & |[a]| $\dots$ & |[a]| $a_{m-2}$ & |[a]| $a_{m-1}$ & |[a]| $a_{m}$\\
  };
  \begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \begin{scope}
      \node[fit=(ma-1-1)(ma-1-6),rounded rectangle,inner sep=0.2em] (l) {};
      \clip(l.west |- l.north) rectangle (ma-1-6.south east |- l.south east);
      \node[fit=(ma-1-1)(ma-1-6),fill=green,box] (l) {};
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}
      \node[fit=(ma-1-7)(ma-1-12),rounded rectangle,inner sep=0.2em] (l) {};
      \clip(ma-1-7.west |- l.north) rectangle (l.east |- l.south);
      \node[fit=(ma-1-7)(ma-1-12),fill=yellow,box] (l) {};
    \end{scope}
    \node[fit=(ma-1-14)(ma-1-19),fill=blue!50,box] {};
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to be precise when clipping as long as you cut out the bit you don't want and keep what you do. So the critical part is just at the meeting point. The rest doesn't really matter.

`matrix of math nodes` would declutter your code a bit and make it easier to read. Also, if you have `box` take an argument, you can write `box=<colour>` rather than `fill=<colour>, box` all the time.

But clipping always feels hackish and inelegant to me, so I don't know whether you consider this an improvement or not. Indeed, I don't know whether I do. It requires hard-coding a bit of extra space at the west end, for example, which is arguably less elegant than your original.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc,matrix,fit,backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  box/.style = {draw, opacity=0.7, inner sep=0.2em, rounded rectangle, fill=#1}
  ]
  \matrix [matrix of math nodes, every node/.append style={draw}, text depth=0.3em, text height=1em, column sep=-\pgflinewidth] (ma) {
     a_1 &  a_2 &  \dots &  a_{m-2} &  a_{m-1} &  a_{m}&
     a_1 &  a_2 &  \dots &  a_{m-2} &  a_{m-1} &  a_{m}&  \dots&
     a_1 &  a_2 &  \dots &  a_{m-2} &  a_{m-1} &  a_{m}\\
  };
  \begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \begin{scope}
      \clip (ma-1-6.east |- current bounding box.south) rectangle ([xshift=-2mm]current bounding box.north west);
      \node[fit=(ma-1-1)(ma-1-6), box=green] (l) {};
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}
      \clip (ma-1-7.west |- current bounding box.south) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
      \node[fit=(ma-1-7)(ma-1-12), box=yellow] (l) {};
    \end{scope}
    \node[fit=(ma-1-14)(ma-1-19), box=blue!50] {};
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: same result]

Comment: Thank you for the tips. I didn't know the current bounding box tips, it's pretty usefull. I don't really like the hard coded xshift, nor the duplicated information (ma-1-7 must be written on the clip and on the rectangle, which is a source of error when I modify my code). But if it's the one solution... I will wait a bit to see if another solution exists before marking it as accepted. Thank you !

Comment: You could add an offset with the calc tikzlibrary, but xshift does the same thing.

Comment: @tobiasBora Well, you have to specify the clipping somehow and it isn't really obvious how else to do it. You could put a new coordinate there and then use its name in the clipping and the node definition, so you'd then only change the definition in one place. But that will probably make the code less readable.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Why load another library just to do something easily done without it? Does that have an advantage I'm not seeing?

Comment: Calc would gives the same problem. What I mean is that here it works well because the node is pretty simple, so only a rough approximation is enough, but for more complex clip, when I do need to know the precice position of the nodes inside the clip (for example if I want to clip exactly at the intersection of two curves), this solution is not usable. I would then need to draw the graphic in an invisible way (how to do that without manually editing each nodes ?), do the clip, and then draw it another time... So I need to duplicate the graph.

Comment: Most of the time you don't have to be precise with clip, so long as it is big enough.  @cfr - I wasn't arguing AGAINST xshift, just explaining what it was doing (the current bounding box isn't big enough to hold the as yet undrawn node).

Comment: @tobiasBora ^^ As John says and as I said, it is rare to need to be that precise. If you really need to be precise, you can use a macro to avoid literally duplicating stuff in the code.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Oh, I see. Sorry, I misunderstood. Or didn't really understand, rather.